# Invalid xmlns value after marshalling XML when using goxmldsig

Tags: xml, go

The code below weirdly adds an xmlns attribute to the root element when marshalling the XML. From what I have read the xmlns attribute should not be explicitly set. But the resulting XML includes the xmlns attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExampleElement xmlns="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" ID="id1234">
...
```

When attempting to validate the XML signature with XMLSecTool I receive the following error:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "xml" cannot be bound to any
>   namespace other than its usual namespace; neither can the namespace
>   for "xml" be bound to any prefix other than "xml".

Is there a valid xmlns attribute value I can use or am I using the libraries incorrectly?

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/tls"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "github.com/beevik/etree"
    "github.com/russellhaering/goxmldsig"
)

type X509KeyStore struct {
    PrivateKey *rsa.PrivateKey
    Cert       []byte
}

func (ks X509KeyStore) GetKeyPair() (*rsa.PrivateKey, []byte, error) {
    return ks.PrivateKey, ks.Cert, nil
}

func failOnError(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%s: %s", msg, err)
    }
}

func main() {
    certBytes := []byte(`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----`)

    keyBytes := []byte(`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`)

    keyPair, err := tls.X509KeyPair(certBytes, keyBytes)
    if err != nil {
        failOnError(err, "invalided to load keypair")
    }
    keyStore := dsig.TLSCertKeyStore(keyPair)

    signingContext := dsig.NewDefaultSigningContext(keyStore)
    signingContext.Canonicalizer = dsig.MakeC14N10ExclusiveCanonicalizerWithPrefixList("xml")
    if err = signingContext.SetSignatureMethod(dsig.RSASHA256SignatureMethod); err != nil {
        failOnError(err, "failed to set signature method")
    }

    elementToSign := &etree.Element{
        Tag: "ExampleElement",
    }
    elementToSign.CreateAttr("ID", "id1234")

    signedAssertionEl, err := signingContext.SignEnveloped(elementToSign)
    if err != nil {
        failOnError(err, "failed to sign envelop")
    }

    var signedAssertionBuf []byte
    {
        doc := etree.NewDocument()
        doc.CreateProcInst("xml", `version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"`)
        doc.SetRoot(signedAssertionEl)
        signedAssertionBuf, err = doc.WriteToBytes()
        if err != nil {
            failOnError(err, "failed to convert doc to bytes")
        }
    }

    ioutil.WriteFile("/tmp/test/example.xml", signedAssertionBuf, 0775)
}
```

Comment: I hope that private key is not used in production...

Comment: Nope, it is a test key :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your namespace is not correctly set. See also [xml namespace](https://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace)

Add the namespace here:

```
elementToSign := &etree.Element{
    Tag: "ExampleElement",
    Space: "xml",
}
elementToSign.CreateAttr("ID", "id1234")
```

With the added line it will pass validation. Tested with [XML Validator](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)